# idpiframe_initialization_failed with People Api

Tags: google-oauth, google-people-api, google-api-js-client

I am testing out the People Api, i started with the [Browser quick start from google](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js)

I have followed all the instructions shown on the quick start.

I also added my localhost url to Authorized origins section on google developer console. I made sure i have the correct api key and client ID.

[image]

When i access the app's url `http://0.0.0.0:8081/` , the page sends back below error

```
People API Quickstart

{
  "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
  "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: http://0.0.0.0:8000 has not been whitelisted for client ID 555307262665-8a97q8pl4etkjh98nvsqnn9hu9ah68bv.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
}
```

I've read online about the issue and most people seemed to have sorted the issue by clearing browser cache.

I've cleared browser cache and enabled `see cookies and site data` for 
[accounts.google.com](http://%20accounts.google.com) on the browser, but that doesn't seem to help, i still get the error.

Is there anything am missing ?

Comment: You are accessing on port 8081 but the error message shows other origin domain on port 8000. Have you tried using port 8000?

Comment: i tried both port 8000 and 8001

Comment: How are you serving your application? Are you using the `simplehttpserver` python package as in the quickstart example?

Comment: Yes, i am using  `simplehttpserver` to server the application, just like in the quickstart example.

Comment: The quickstart is working as it is. Did you change anything in the code? Why are you serving on two different ports?

Comment: I tried http://0.0.0.0:8000 but it is saying that it should be top level domain like .com , .org. Can we not test people api on localhost?